# PHP File Down with header()

Tags: php, header, content-type, mime

I have written the following code to allow download of files without the source being displayed.

In this example, the file 'test.pdf' is downloaded, but its corrupt.

Can anyone see any reason this would be the case?

```
$path = 'http://www.domain.org/images/uploads/test.pdf';

// Directory Path
$directory_path_filename = str_replace('http://www.domain.org/', '', $path);

$filepath = '/var/sites/l/domain.org/public_html/'.$directory_path_filename;

if ( file_exists( $filepath ) ) {

    $finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ' . basename( $filepath ) );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filepath ) );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    finfo_close( $finfo );

    ob_clean( );
    flush( );
    readfile( $filepath );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this method

$file receive the full path, $filename is the download filename.

```
public static function downloadFile($file, $filename)
    {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = '.basename($filename));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check = 0, pre-check = 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            die;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pedro. Thank you, but this still results in the same issue. The file can not be opened once downloaded.

Comment: In that case probably you have some output before the headers... like a noite or something, could you please post the full code?